# What can I do that make it shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

just like in question. What should I do? I thought that make Objects, but I do not know does it make sense.

```
let seccont = document.querySelector("#security_content");
let subcont = document.querySelector("#sub_content");

var accbtn = document.querySelector(".account");
var secbtn = document.querySelector(".security");
var subbtn = document.querySelector(".subscription");

accbtn.onclick = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Account />, acccont);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(seccont);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(subcont);
    seccont.classList.add('hidden');
    acccont.classList.remove('hidden');
    subbtn.classList.remove("selected");
    secbtn.classList.remove("selected");
    accbtn.classList.add("selected");
  }
  secbtn.onclick = () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<Security />, seccont);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(acccont);
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(subcont);
    acccont.classList.add('hidden');
    seccont.classList.remove('hidden');
    accbtn.classList.remove("selected");
    subbtn.classList.remove("selected");
    secbtn.classList.add("selected");
  }
subbtn.onclick = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(<Subscription />, subcont);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(seccont);
  ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(acccont);
  acccont.classList.add('hidden');
  seccont.classList.add('hidden');
  subcont.classList.remove('hidden');
  secbtn.classList.remove("selected");
  accbtn.classList.remove("selected");
  subbtn.classList.add("selected");
}
```

### There is a "ReactDOM" just I have more code in React

```
class Account extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const goto = () => {window.open("/pixels/home/", "_self");}
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className="options">
          <li>
            <span>Login</span>
            <input type="text" autoComplete="off" id="login" name="login">
            </input>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Email</span>
            <input type="text" autoComplete="off" id="email" name="email">
            </input>
          </li>
          <li>
            <span>Nickname</span>
            <input type="text" autoComplete="off" id="nick" name="nick">
            </input>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <button id="apply_acc" onClick={goto}>Save</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
class Security extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const goto = () => {window.open("/pixels/home/", "_self");}
        return (
            <div>
            <ul className="options">
            <li>
                <span>Old password</span>
                <input type="password" id="old_pwd" name="oldpwd"></input>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>New password</span>
                <input type="password" id="new_pwd" name="newpwd"></input>
            </li>
            <li>
                <span>Repeat password</span>
                <input type="password" id="newpwd_repeat" name="newpwdrep"></input>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button id="apply_sec" onClick={goto}>Save</button>
        </div>
        );
    }
}
class Subscription extends React.Component {
  render() {
      return (
          <div>
          <button>TODO</button>
      </div>
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe switch to using [React Router](https://reactrouter.com/)? It may make your life a little simpler.

Comment: Please add html part